# Weird CSS spacing everywhere

Tags: html, css

Okay So I made a template with some CSS & HTML. However, if you look between the menubar, there's a bunch of white space. Also the content and sidebar are weird. If you look at the top there's a bunch of padding at the top but I didn't apply any padding anywhere! Help!

Link to site http://techtubecentral.com/demo/

Comment: Try to isolate your problem. It will be easier for us to solve it. thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Naveen's solution is correct b/c there is default margin coming from the browser's style sheet. Add

```
* {margin:0; padding:0;}
```

as the first line in your style sheet - it's a simple reset of these properties on all elements, and you will have no more trouble with "phantom" paddings and margins cascading down from the browser stylesheets.

Comment: A better solution would be to simply use some reset or normalize css sheet as he does not have one and it's generally considered best practice to do so.

Comment: best explanation! Fixed everything. It doens't effect other things that I change the padding on. So anytime I need to reset a section to something I can just use a "*"? Cool thanks

Comment: * simply means a wild card (anything) so if you use it on its own as I did in the example above it affects every element. If you write: div * {some CSS} that affects all elements inside divs.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, Hope it will work

```
 <style type="text/css">    
    ul{
     margin:0px;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Padding and margin is specified by default.  It is part of what was originally generated by the W3C consortium.  All you need is a CSS Reset sheet.

http://www.cssreset.com/

You can attach this to your site as a separate file, for example reset.css.  Or you can jsut copy paste the reset code to the top of your styles.css file.

Answer (score 0):

When using a  tag you will find that the browser will automatically adding a margin and sometimes padding that may not be needed.

Try adding margin: 0px; and padding: 0px; just as good practice.